# Captured Photo orientation is changing in android

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I'am opening camera app on click of a button. And displaying the captured photo in next activity. But the captured photo is rotating by 90 degrees. When I display the image in a view after I capture it, it's orientation is always landscape. Why is the photo not being shown in portrait as is when the photo is taken in portrait mode?

onClick of a button :

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(APP_DIR+"/latest.png")));       
startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_PHOTO_CONSTANT);
```

Inside onActvityresult:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(APP_DIR+"/latest.png");
startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplayActivity.class));
```

Displaying captured photo:

```
photoViewRelativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), CaptureActivity.bmp));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android)

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem mostly with the Samsung handsets.Apparently Samsung phones set the EXIF orientation tag, rather than rotating individual pixels.Reading the Bitmap using BitmapFactory does not support this tag.What i found the solution to this problem was using ExifInterface in onActivityResult method of the activity.Which checks for orientation associated with URI of the captured image from the camera.

```
                        int rotate = 0;
                        try {
                            getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
                            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
                            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(
                                    imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                            switch (orientation) {
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                rotate = 270;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                rotate = 180;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                rotate = 90;
                                break;
                            }
                            Log.v(Common.TAG, "Exif orientation: " + orientation);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        /****** Image rotation ****/
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        matrix.postRotate(orientation);
                        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, x, y, width, height, matrix, true);
```

Comment: Do i need to rotate the bitmap at the end ?

Comment: you need to rotate the bitmap at the end.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But i have a small doubt. We are rotating the image after capturing it. Does it rotate the photo captured in other than samsung devices also? What if the photo is captured properly in XXXX device?

Comment: In other devices int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
function returns 0 angle so switch statement never gets called so the orientation remains as it is.

Comment: I am facing serious issue with code.. samsung galaxy s4 device getting   restart .. can you help me ? why this happening?

Comment: I just wonder where to put those code on my app. Should I put it on ActivityResult?

Comment: @Raditya Kurnianto : onActivityResult()

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha Can you please tell me how to rotate image with after your code?

Comment: @ShabbirPanjesha what is scaled here in - Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, x, y, width, height, matrix, true);?

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra : 'scaled' (its was my personal requirement) here is newly created Bitmap from file 'imageFile'

Comment: But in samsung S4 orientation always returned 0

Comment: Just want to let you know that EXIF is not really a reliable solution as manufacturer tend no to implement this on their devices.

Answer (score 4):

> call this method with path of bitmap and bitmap

```
   getRotateImage(path, bm)
```

> Add getRotateImage method as static in any util class and use it.

```
public static Bitmap getRotateImage(String photoPath, Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
        switch (orientation) {

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                break;

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            default:
                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        return rotatedBitmap;

    }


  public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use Glide instead. It fixes the orientation itself and is irrespective of the mobile you're using. Here\s a sample

```
Glide.with(_c).load(horizontalList.get(position).imagePath).into(holder.img_injury);
```

Comment: Great answer Syeda

Comment: It works in original image. But It doesn't work after resizing image

Answer (score 1):

I got it somewhat working. When I take the photo in Landscape mode everything works fine as before. If I take the photo in portrait mode, I need to turn the camera upside down and the pic looks good. If you notice I changed your code a bit by adding the "ExifInterface" in front of each orientation. I used the following code:

```
    try {
      ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename); 
      int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 
                          ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
      int rotate = 0;
         switch(orientation) {
            case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                 rotate-=90;break;
            case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                 rotate-=90;break;
            case  ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                 rotate-=90;break;
            }
              Log.d("Fragment", "EXIF info for file " + filename + ": " + rotate);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.d("Fragment", "Could not get EXIF info for file " + filename + ": " + e);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just simpaly rotate it

get the orietation of the image taken using this code in onActvityresult ....

```
File imageFile = new File(imageUri.toString());
       ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
       int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
       int rotate = 0;
       switch(orientation) {
         case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
             rotate-=90;break;
         case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
             rotate-=90;break
         case ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
             rotate-=90;break
       }
```

Comment: What are the values of ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270, ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 and ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 as I am getting cannot resolve symbol error for all of them.