# display image as it captured in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, orientation, image-capture

I'm trying to make Image captured by the camera by using [Camera View lib](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView)

Unfortunately, the lib does not support the issue of image rotation in some devices like Samsung.

after long of search, I found out that I can fix it by getting the rotated value like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069122/camera-orientation-issue-in-android?rq=1) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026615/captured-photo-orientation-is-changing-in-android) 
but It not solved my issue.

what I need is if user captured Image in any mode **(Default Portrait- Default
Landscape- Other
Landscape- Other Portrait)** is displayed as it.

this is code for getting orientation.

```
private int getRightRotationAngel(byte[] data) {

        ExifInterface exifInterface;
        try {
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
        int orientation;
        int rotationDegrees = 0;
        orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt
                (ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotationDegrees = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotationDegrees = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotationDegrees = 270;
                break;

        }
        return rotationDegrees;
    }
```

this is code for setting rotation

```
private void setImageInCorrectRotation(byte[] data) {
        int rotateDegree = getRightRotationAngel(data);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        Toast.makeText(FrameViewerActivity.this, rotateDegree + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (rotateDegree != 0)
            matrix.postRotate(rotateDegree);

        mCapturedImageCopy = Bitmap.createBitmap(mCapturedImageCopy, 0, 0,
                mCapturedImageCopy.getWidth(), mCapturedImageCopy.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        showImage(mCapturedImageCopy);

    }
```

hope to get help from anyone

> Edit 1: **showImage()** method work to display the rotated
>   mCapturedImageCopy

Comment: What goes wrong on your Samsung device? Does it report wrong **exifInterface**?

Comment: I don't know if it wrong or not but when I display value got by ExifInterface if get 

Other portrait/ code 90: view rotated 180

Default landscape/ code 0:  view rotated 90

Other landscape/ code 180:  view rotated 90